# what is the best way to retrieve multiple data from smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am done with my smart contract part, and working on front end part using react. There are a lot of state variable  that I want to retrieve to use them on web page, but I am not sure what is the best way to get many state variables with ease. Should I make a structure that stores multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this library : [web3react](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react). It will help you handle all the connections between your smart-contract ad your front, connect with metamask, ...